# Can Math SE rearrange the textbox and the preview box into two column?

Tags: feature-request, markdown-preview

Can Math SE rearrange the textbox and the preview box into two column?
Like the following figure.
I think it is more convenience for use.

[image]

Comment: [See this script.](http://stackapps.com/questions/2245/stack-exchange-side-by-side-edit-and-preview)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, I wasn't able to get the script you linked to work, but [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260586/231209) did work for me. It only works for new answers and questions, not for editing. The script moves the answer pane to the right and the preview to the left but it's pretty easy to switch them (if anyone needs help with that feel free to ask).

Comment: I've made some modifications to ᔕᖺᘎᕊ's script in my comment above to give it some more features. Now it works when editing existing questions and answers too. Check out its [post on StackApps](http://stackapps.com/q/6461/36263) for more info.