# How do I preview my post before posting?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, markdown-preview

How do I preview my post before posting? I do not find any preview button.

Comment: Type it and the text is showed below as long as you format it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA is correct (+1). Just scroll down a little and you will see it.

Comment: Although this doesn’t apply on mobile Safari (and I assume other mobile browsers). It will show up on the desktop version of the site.

Comment: Are you referring to questions or answers? For the questions indeed it is an issue.

Comment: I'm routinely doing this in Chrome on an Android phone, but I think I had to tap the "main site" link to get it to work. I get previews for questions and answers but not comments.

Comment: I really wish the preview was scrollable separately, since I tend to write long answers, and jumping between the edit window and the end of my answer is a pain...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This is a digression from the original question, but I will mention that one of the answers here mention something similar to your suggestion: [Question and preview might be better side-by-side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70703). Having preview next to the editing box was discussed also on this meta: [Can Math SE rearrange the textbox and the preview box into two column?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21636) and [Editing panel and preview side-by-side - fighting lag on large answers!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10505)

Answer (score 4):

There is no "preview button".

Just to confirm information in the comments, and to check whether asking a question presented an issue with respect to seeing a preview, I posted the following "example question":

---

[image]

Note the text and formatting I typed in the question field (labeled "body" in the image below).  Also note that directly below the question field ("body") in which we type/format a question, is a preview of the text/formatting as it renders, from the question field.

---

We observe that the title is not available for preview, in terms of how it will appear in the posted question.  One can always copy and paste the title and insert at the very top (or bottom) of the body, prior to posting, to ensure it renders properly, and if edits to the title are needed, edit.  Then before submitting the question, simply remember to remove the copy and paste of the question in the body, and you are good to go.

Note that my screenshot comes from a notebook pc; I cannot speak for previews on mobile devices.

Comment: If anyone would like to play with slightly enlarging the screenshot, the edit would be most welcome.

Comment: The only issue, if I'm not wrong, I think is that we can't see a preview for the title when it contains formulas. But we can copy that in the text and see how it looks like.

Comment: @gimusi Yes, the problem with *titles* was mentioned a few times. Some related posts on this meta: [Latex preview on question title?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20248) and [Why not add the title of the question in the preview while writing it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25252). (And on Meta Stack Exchange: [Please include the title in the question preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115247).)

Comment: Note to future readers: This is only valid on the computer webpage. On the Android app, for example, there is a Preview button on the top right of the page.