# Double column when editing a post

Tags: feature-request, markdown-preview, editor

> I'm still not clear on the use of this part of Stack Exchange but since there is the "feature-request" tag I think this is the right place to ask this question (which is actually not a question but a kind of proposal).

I would like that when we edit a post the screen is divided into two columns or two boxes in which you can scroll parallel to the text you are editing (code on the left and preview on the right).
Essentially this need arises from the fact that many long posts have very similar lines to each other and during the editing phase it is easy to get confused when you are looking at LaTeX code and it becomes inconvenient to go up and down every time to check that you are not making a mistake.

Comment: On [meta.se]: [Question and preview might be better side-by-side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70703).
Some relate dposts on this meta: [Ask Question app should have side-by-side view option](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25179), 
[Feature request - but it woudn't be a feature, it'd be a blessing - editing panel and preview side-by-side - fighting lag on large answers!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10505),
[Can Math SE rearrange the textbox and the preview box into two column?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21636), etc.

Comment: What you describe is available (side-by-side editing of Markdown and $\LaTeX$) on the third party site [StackEdit.io](https://stackedit.io).